# Run a query and make it suitable for coding

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This question might be lazy question. While I was using netbean to run query and also sql workbench then each time I run query and use it in `.java` file as

```
String sql = "select * from some table "+
             "where table.col = 'sth'" //the query is not this short
```

Adding + and "" easily without going to each line and adding in 100 line of query.
Is there any way that `netbeans` or `Oracle sql developer` support direct export ast this kind of string or is there any other alternative.

Comment: you want to have the query in a single place - reusable code?

Comment: @FlorinGhita no I would like to create query using visual tool and add the *""* and *+* automatically

Comment: Your question says "SQL Workbench" but it's tagged with "MySQL Workbench. Which one are you using? Those are two different tools.

Comment: consider using iBatis or MyBatis.

Comment: @Kitex: ah, none of those. SQL Workbench/J would have been able to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Advance Format** you can. HUrray! IN oracle SQl Developer[image]